# How to show loading message while making a json request on windows phone?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone, loading

I need to show a loading message, while a json request is made on windows phone, like a async task with a ProgressDialog on Android, where I put a dialog.show() on onPreExecute() and a dialog.dismiss() on onPostExecute. How can I do it on windows phone?

Here is my json request:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
    webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?&query=taxi&location=-19.94549444,-43.92314218&&radius=5000&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDucC8QBV5wu4V-dQXFfABXGaaUzdmT5xw"));
```

While this request is downloading, i need to show the loading message, and ent it when the request is complete.

Comment: The solution in the deleted post doesn't work?

Comment: For me don't work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can display a progress bar to indicate a ongoing process.
Just put the code as follows:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);

ProgressIndicator progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator() {
    IsVisible = true,
    IsIndeterminate = false,
    Text = "Loading..." 
};

SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(this, progressIndicator);
webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?&query=taxi&location=-19.94549444,-43.92314218&&radius=5000&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDucC8QBV5wu4V-dQXFfABXGaaUzdmT5xw"));
```

This will display a progress bar as your request begin to execute.
To stop this after the load, add following code to event handler:

```
void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(s, e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () =>
    {
        progressIndicator.IsVisible = false;
        // Your code
    });
}
```

Comment: @DanielNazareth: Pleasure :)

Comment: How to place this loading in the center of the screen ?